VSCode Automatic Type Acquisition not working with ESM project
I recenty upgraded my commonjs project to ESM.
As a result however many of my imports no longer have type hinting or code completion (usually older cjs packages).
When the project was in commonjs VSCode would automatically get the type definitions from the @types package (DefinitelyTyped on github).
Now it appears I have to manually install them.
Why?
Is there any way to get the old behaviour back?
EDIT:
An example package that I used to have types for but no longer do would be fs-extra:
import fs from "fs-extra";

However after some more testing, I found that type acquisition is longer working in CJS projects either.
I use the fs-extra package all the time and I know it was typed until recently.
I also have this problem with several other widely used packages, I believe they are all written in CJS.

Also I have found that my %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\TypeScript folder contains 3 directories: 5.5, 5.6 & 5.7
5.5 is full of all my automatically acquired types, the other 2 folders are empty except for a bare package.json.
For some reason the latest versions of Typescript are not working with this feature.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre]?

In providing an example I've noticed it's not just for this project but for all projects. Must be something wrong with my installation...

Did you reinstall the packages after changing ts version?

Yes. I've continued my investigation to the root of the problem, re-installed vscode, deleted all settings, removed all extensions, etc. What finally got it working again was installing an older version of VSCode August 2024 (version 1.93). The latest version is bugged.
